# Images blinks on scroll ? (Without using lazy-load)

Tags: image, angular, google-chrome, scroll, lazy-loading

In my angular application i have a page with 25 [carousels](https://github.com/benjamincharity/angular-flickity) and ~600 images.

Each image size is nearly 40-50kb, and on scroll images start blinks (see image bellow) only in chrome.
I don't use any lazyload library for images.

What is the reason and how i can fix that?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not such a bad idea just to pre-load your images in a simplest way like

```
const preloadImages = (urls) =>
  Promise.all(urls.map(url =>
    new Promise(resolve => {
      const img = new Image();
      img.onload = () => resolve(img);
      img.onerror = () => resolve(img);
      img.src = url;
    })
  ));
```

Comment: thanks for answer. i find similar issue : https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/4dj7t3/chrome_flickering_while_scrolling/?st=j876r1n2&sh=f912cb73

Comment: cant understand , if its possible to fix this bug from front-end part of website

Comment: If you think that it relates to Chrome smooth-scrolling setting, you would try to play with `chrome://flags/#disable-smooth-scrolling` (per your link). As a second attempt I'd recommend to lazy-load images. If it will not help, I'd consider that this is Chrome issue which does not relate to smooth-scrolling and images pre-loading.

Comment: I can disable it for me, but its still will be visible for other users with this option... I start to use lazy-load , but no difference ...